# javascript error only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I get this error, only in IE:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 56
Sign: 5
Code: 0
```

Javascript code:

```
    function recalcTotalPrice(item) {
    values = $("input", item).serialize();
    $.post( url,
           values,
           function (data,textStatus, jqXHR) {
              variant_wrapper = $(item).parents(".variant");
              $(".price", variant_wrapper).html(data.total_price);
56:           updateProductPrice(item);
           })
  };

  function updateProductPrice(item) {
    wrapper = $(item).parents('.advertising_product');
    $(".total_price", wrapper).html(sum($(".price", wrapper).map(function() {return parseFloat($(this).html())}).toArray()));
  };
```

Anyone?

---

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the rendered HTML code that triggers the javascript:

```
<li>
        <label class="month" for="month">Mar</label>
          <div class="week ">
            <input id="386_1_10" name="book[]weeks[]" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="1|10" />
            <label for="386_1_10">10</label>
          </div>
          <div class="week ">
            <input id="386_1_11" name="book[]weeks[]" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="1|11" />
            <label for="386_1_11">11</label>
          </div>
          <div class="week ">
            <input id="386_1_12" name="book[]weeks[]" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="1|12" />
            <label for="386_1_12">12</label>
          </div>
          <div class="week ">
            <input id="386_1_13" name="book[]weeks[]" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="1|13" />
            <label for="386_1_13">13</label>
          </div>
      </li>

<script>
  $('#item_386.week_picker_wrapper').weekPicker(
      {
          url: '/products/100/items/386/calc_total_price'
       }
    );
</script>
```

When the Checkbox is clicked the javascript is called.

Here is the full javascript code:

```
jQuery.fn.weekPicker = function(options) {
  var self = this;
  var week_picker = new WeekPicker(options, self);
}

jQuery.fn.weekLocker = function() {
  var self = this;
  var week_picker = new WeekLocker(self);
};

WeekPicker = function(options, selector) {

  var url = options.url;
  var yearPos = 0;

  $("a.prev_year", selector).click(function() {
    if (yearPos > 0) {
      $(".year", selector).css("margin-left", --yearPos * -55)
      $(".week_picker", selector).css("margin-left", yearPos * -185)
    }
    return false;
  })

  $("a.next_year", selector).click(function() {
    if (yearPos < 2) {
      $(".year", selector).css("margin-left", ++yearPos * -55)
      $(".week_picker", selector).css("margin-left", yearPos * -185)
    }
    return false;
  })

  $(".disabled input[type='checkbox'], .busy input[type='checkbox'], .locked input[type='checkbox']", selector).click(function () {
    return false;
  })

  $("input[type='checkbox']", selector).change(function() {
    recalcTotalPrice(selector);
  });

  function getValues(selection) {
    return selection.map(function() {return $(this).html()}).toArray().join(",")
  }

  function recalcTotalPrice(item) {
    values = $("input", item).serialize();
    $.post( url,
           values,
           function (data,textStatus, jqXHR) {
              variant_wrapper = $(item).parents(".variant");
              $(".price", variant_wrapper).html(data.total_price);
              updateProductPrice(item);
           })
  };

  function updateProductPrice(item) {
    var wrapper = $(item).parents('.advertising_product');
    $(".total_price", wrapper).html(sum($(".price", wrapper).map(function() {return parseFloat($(this).html())}).toArray()));
  };

  function sum(arr) {
    for(var s = 0, i = arr.length; i; s += arr[--i]);
    return s;
  };

  recalcTotalPrice(selector);
};
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

I got rid of the nasty errors, so now I "only" have one more problem.
This function, wont fire in IE7, IE8

```
$("input[type='checkbox']", selector).change(function() {
    recalcTotalPrice(selector);
  });
```

I suspect the it is the "change" that dosent work in IE. I have found this http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?626340-jQuery-change()-event-in-IE-not-triggering-properly-with-checkbox

But I don't know how to implement it into my code.

Comment: Which IE? And can you provide a demo?

Comment: The problem is that item is not a dom object. So the real error is not on line 56, but on the line, where updateProductPrice is called.

Comment: I have just updated the code with the function and line where the function is called.

Comment: Yes but you still haven't shown where  "item" gets its value.  What is it?

Comment: @JaredFarrish can you show how that is done?

Comment: Give @Pointy's solution a shot. Closure scope always throws me a bit; looking at it, I don't think `item` is available, but it's possible it is because it was passed to the original function. `:s`

Comment: @andkjaar JaredFarrish is asking you to show the call to `recalcTotalPrice`. That is where item is defined.

Comment: There's really no reason to pass "item" around at all, since all those functions defined inside "WeekPicker" will have access to the value of "selector" anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's simply that **you forgot `var`** !

```
var wrapper = $(item).parents('.advertising_product');
```

Comment: How is that going to fix the problem?

Comment: I don't believe that IE likes mentions of global variables (window properties) that are undefined like that.

Comment: IE doesn't like a global variable to be declared in a function? Wouldn't that cause all sorts of problems?

Comment: No - that "wrapper" variable was (according to the posted code) not declared *anywhere*.  IE (I think - jsfiddle is having IE problems today, grrrr ...) does not like an assignment like that because there's no property on the `window` object called "wrapper".

Comment: The other issue is that IE is complaining that the property is not available. That will occur before it complains about the `wrapper` being global, because `wrapper = ...` is the final portion of the statement execution.

Comment: I think that the "property" IE is complaining about **is** "wrapper", and the "object" is `window` :-)

Comment: IE doesn't complain that `window` doesn't support that property, only that the `Object` prototype doesn't have it. Then again, I'm always confused what IE exactly means with their errors ;)

Comment: @Jared Farrish what is your favorite tool to test in every IE?

Comment: @Ryan - IE9 lets you switch the browser mode using `F12` developer tools.

Comment: Well maybe you're right, Jared, but I can't get jsfiddle itself to work at all in IE8 today :(

Comment: That is weird; I had no problems (using IE9). Is it possible it is a scope issue on `item`? Closures on functions confuse me, but when I look at it, that's what I see. But even that I'm not sure, since if I call `test()` in my fiddle without any argument, it doesn't throw an error either. Hmm...

Comment: @Jared Farrish closures are not an issue here, because `item` is in the local scope for `recalcTotalPrice`. It would be an issue, if he redefined a closure scope in `recalcTotalPrice` AND he returned a function in `recalcTotalPrice` (to get that closure scope into another scope).

Comment: @Ryan - It's the `$.post()` success handler that I'm thinking about being out of scope. The only way I *can* get an error is to try to call `test(item)` and `item` doesn't exist as a variable (in any scope), but it points to jQuery, not back to the calling function (at least in IE9). http://jsfiddle.net/MbyLu/1/

Comment: @Jared Farrish ya, it gets hairy with callbacks, but in this case, he defined an anonymous function inline, so he would've had to set up a closure scope in the anonymous function or jQuery would have to set one up for the callback. All jQuery is going to do is properly set `this` based on either the scope object you sent in, or, as you noted, jQuery itself. However, `this` is not present in his anonymous callback; therefore, I suspect that `item` passed to `recalTotalPrice` is wrong.

Comment: Also, he is passing `item`to `$`, which means it's supposed to be a wrapped set. Meaning, he might've found a problem with jQuery not being IE-compatible for `$.parents`. Or, the problem could be that if jQuery doesn't get expected input to `$`, then it might have an IE-specific issue of not being able to gracefully recover. All in all, though, it looks like jQuery has something wrong in IE.

Comment: @andkjaer amazingly, you still have not shown what calls jQuery.weekPicker()!

Comment: @Pointy sorry about that, i have added it to the html code above

Comment: You can use "click" instead of "change" to get checkbox events reliably in IE.